# I need a single line array. I am using nested loops to push elements into the array. The array contains multipe lines

Tags: arrays, perl, push

I am using perl to produce an array of elements arranged as a single, tab-delimited line. However, only a portion of my array is like this. Other parts get printed as separate lines.

Below is the relevant portion of the code.

It is a foreach loop that has three conditional `for` loops embedded in it. The `push` command is used four times at four different `if`/`else` conditions. The particular array I'm having the issue with is called `@imputed_positions`. Several variables are defined near the beginning, which can be ignored. I don't think those are the problem.

The output I get is correctly printed as a single line when the variable `$distance` is`> 1`, even though those values get processed by 3 separate instances of the push command (the first three). Values for `$distance` that are `> 1` and also floating point values for $distance get printed as a single line. When `$distance` is `< 1` or `= 1`, they get printed as separate lines. These lines correspond to elements pushed into @imputed_positions by the last of the four push commands.

I can't recognize an analogous problem within "Similar Questions," probably because I don't have a precise enough clue of what the issue is.

Thanks!!!

```
foreach my $distance ( @distances ) {

    if ( $distance > 1 &&
       ( int ( $distance ) != $distance ) ) {       ###just asking whether $variable is an integer and whether it is > than 1.

        my $rounded_up = rounding_up( $distance );
        my $rounded_down = rounding_down( $distance );

        my $up_distance = $distance/$rounded_up;
        my $down_distance = $distance/$rounded_down;

        my $abs_up = abs ( 1 - $up_distance );
        my $abs_down = abs ( 1 - $down_distance );  

        if ( $abs_up < $abs_down ) {
            for ( my $i = 0; $i < $rounded_up; $i++ ) {
                push ( @imputed_positions, "IMP!$up_distance!A\tIMP!$up_distance!D\tIMP!$up_distance!I\t" );
            }
        }
        else {
            for ( my $i = 0; $i < $rounded_down; $i++ ){
                push ( @imputed_positions, "IMP!$down_distance!A\tIMP!$down_distance!D\tIMP!$down_distance!I\t" );
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( $distance > 1 ){

            for ( my $i = 1; $i <= $distance; $i++ ) {
                push ( @imputed_positions, "IMP!1!A\tIMP!1!D\tIMP!1!I\t" );
            }
        }
        else {
            push ( @imputed_positions, "IMP!$distance!A\tIMP!$distance!D\tIMP!$distance!I\t" );
        }
    }
}

#print @imputed_positions;

#rounding down subroutine
sub rounding_down {
    my ( $round_me ) = @_;
    my $rounded_down = int( $round_me );
    return $rounded_down;
}

#rounding up subroutine
sub rounding_up {
    my ( $round_me ) = @_;
    my $rounded_up = int( $round_me ) + 1;
    return $rounded_up;
}
```

Maybe it would help if I explained the input. The @distances is just a txt file, where each line is a number. The numbers are all positive, and can be 0, integers, or floating point numbers. For eg, `@distance = ( 1, 3, 5.9999, 4.9, 3.1, 3.000001, 0, 0, 0.3 )`.

When `@distance` contains the above elements, the output does not print as a single line, but rather looks like:

```
IMP!1
!A      IMP!1
!D      IMP!1
!I      IMP!1!A IMP!1!D IMP!1!I IMP!1!A IMP!1!D IMP!1!I IMP!1!A IMP!1!D            IMP!1!IIMP!0.999999998333333!A   IMP!0.999999998333333!D IMP!0.999999998333333!I IMP!0.999999998333333!A IMP!0.999999998333333!D IMP!0.999999998333333!I IMP!0.999999998333333!A IMP!0.999999998333333!D IMP!0.999999998333333!I IMP!0.999999998333333!AIMP!0.999999998333333!D  IMP!0.999999998333333!I IMP!0.999999998333333!A IMP!0.999999998333333!D IMP!0.999999998333333!I IMP!0.999999998333333!A IMP!0.999999998333333!D IMP!0.999999998333333!I IMP!0.98!A  IMP!0.98!D  IMP!0.98!I  IMP!0.98!A  IMP!0.98!D  IMP!0.98!I  IMP!0.98!A  IMP!0.98!D  IMP!0.98!I  IMP!0.98!A  IMP!0.98!D  IMP!0.98!I  IMP!0.98!A  IMP!0.98!D  IMP!0.98!I  IMP!1.03333333333333!A  IMP!1.03333333333333!D  IMP!1.03333333333333!I  IMP!1.03333333333333!A  IMP!1.03333333333333!D  IMP!1.03333333333333!I  IMP!1.03333333333333!A  IMP!1.03333333333333!D  IMP!1.03333333333333!I  IMP!1.00000003333333!A  IMP!1.00000003333333!D  IMP!1.00000003333333!I  IMP!1.00000003333333!A  IMP!1.00000003333333!D      IMP!1.00000003333333!I  IMP!1.00000003333333!A  IMP!1.00000003333333!D  IMP!1.00000003333333!I   IMP!0
!A      IMP!0
!D      IMP!0
!I      IMP!0
!A      IMP!0
!D      IMP!0
!I      IMP!0.3
!A      IMP!0.3
!D      IMP!0.3
!I
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you expect and the output you actually get?

Comment: Hi, yes I can @WinnieNicklaus. Will try to format this reply correctly. Output expected: `IMP!1A    IMP!1D    IMP!1I   IMP!0.01A    IMP!0.01D    IMP!0.001I ...` all as a single line for any value of $distance.  What is see when I print is a separate line for each block of "IMP!$distance!A\tIMP!$distance!D\tIMP!$distance!I\t"  whenever the $distance is 1 or < 1.

Comment: thanks! @amon for the revisions to my post. I'm new to this site and am learning how to format posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the error is happening further up in your code, where you bring in the distances.  It appears that you are not stripping the trailing newline from your input lines.

When you perform some computation with `$distance`, Perl treats it as an integer.  But unless you have explicitly converted `$distance` to a numeric type (e.g., `$distance += 0;`), it is treated as a string whenever possible, and so when you insert it into a string, your string will have newlines in it.

If you have code similar to the following:

```
while(my $line = <INPUT>) {
    # Do some stuff with $line
}
```

Change it to:

```
while(my $line = <INPUT>) {
    chomp $line;
    # Now do your stuff with $line
}
```

See the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks! I added `chomp $distances;` right after the foreach command at the top of the code. I get a single line. It looks correct. Thanks!!! I thought it was a problem with `push', not in how perl deals with integers. I wouldn't have looked for that in the Similar Questions. Where can I read more about this issue?

Comment: Google "strongly typed" and "weakly typed" to learn more about how various languages behave.  Perl is a notable weakly typed language, in which different types of variables can be mixed and the interpreter will attempt to Do The Right Thing.

Another good thing to review would be Perl "context".  This is similar -- for example, if you use an array in "scalar context", Perl will not complain, it will try to do something reasonable, namely return the size of the array.